# Analytical aptitude - Division of exponentials.

Tags: exponential-function

What is the remainder when 6^17 + 117^6  is divided by 7?

How to approach these type of questions?

Comment: We have $6=7-1$ and $117=7\cdot 17-2$. Expanding, we find that the remainder is the same as the remainder of $(-1)^{17}+(-2)^{6}$, easy to compute. And small!

Comment: How did you reach (−1)^17+(−2)^6?

Comment: Well, when I did it I actually used congruences, but tried to phrase things without using the term, because it may not be familiar to you. Imagine for example using the Binomial Theorem to expand $(7-1)^{17}$. There will be a bunch of terms divisible by $7$ and higher powers of $7$, with a $(-1)^{17}$ at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps a lot to know about [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  Then you see that

$$6\equiv-1\mod 7\qquad\text{and}\qquad117\equiv-2\mod7$$

and thus

$$6^{17}+117^6\equiv(-1)^{17}+(-2)^6=-1+64=63\equiv0\mod7$$

It helps even more to know about [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), because then you would know that $117^6\equiv1\mod7$ directly (as soon as you check that $7$ doesn't divide $117$).

Comment: I had to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0ZQvZLx2KA to fully understand it! Thanks

Comment: We find the 6^17 part just as @rgettman's answer says, then use Fermats theorem, 7 is a prime number and it doesnt divide 117, so 117^6 is congruent to 1 mod 7.

Comment: and then we add the equations because of modulo arithmetic, to get 0.

Comment: I got this one, but have no idea if I will be able to solve twisted questions of this type...

Comment: @PrakashWadhwani, give yourself time, and keep at it!

Comment: The test is tomorrow! :)

Answer (score 0):

$6^{17} = (7-1)^{17} = (-1)^{17} + \text{multiples of }7$
$117^6 = (7\times 17 - 2)^6 = (-2)^6 + \text{multiples of }7
$
sum up the two quantities, you get$$
6^{17}+
117^6 = 63 + \text{a multiple of }7 = \text{a multiple of }7 
$$
so the reminder is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use arithmetic $\pmod 7$.  Specifically we'll use these facts:

$x^n \pmod y \equiv (x \pmod y)^n \pmod y$

and

$(y - 1) \pmod y \equiv (-1) \pmod y$

Using those facts...

$6^{17} + 117^6 \pmod 7 \equiv$

$(-1)^{17} + (5)^6 \pmod 7$

$5^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ and $5^4 \equiv 4^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$, so

$-1 + (4 \times 2) \equiv 0 \pmod 7$

Comment: thanks a lot! I didnt get the last two lines but solved the question using the answer below!